# A limit theorem in Rudin. Please elaborate?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Theorem: Let $\{ p_n \} \in X $. If $E \subset X$ and $p$ is a limit point of $E$, then there is a sequence $\{ p_n \}$ such that $p = \lim p_n $

The proof goes like this

> **proof**: For each positive integer $n$, there is a point $p_n \in E$ such that $d(p_n, p)   < 1/n$. Given $\epsilon > 0,$ choose $N$ so that $N \epsilon > 1.$ If $n > N$, it follows $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$. Hence $p_n \to p$

**Q1**: How come he starts out saying "there is a point $p_n \in E$"? Isn't this what is he trying to prove? The existence of a sequence? He starts out by assuming it exists.

**Q2**: When he chooses $N$, why does he write it in the following manner "*choose $N$ so that $N \epsilon > 1.$*"? Why doesn't he write $N > 1/\epsilon$? Is he using Archimedean? How does he know he wants $N \epsilon > 1$? Note that I am not asking "why he chose $N > 1/\epsilon$", I am asking why does he write it like this?

**definition**:A point $p$ is a limit point of $E \subset X$, if every neighbourhood $N_r(p) \cap E - \{ p \} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: For Q2 it's the same, I would actually think that the best way would be to say that $\epsilon > 1/N$, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Javier, yes that is something I would expect to see, but his way I can't follow, but I want to know what he was thinking.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't like how \frac{}{} and */* look withtout a proper display?

Comment: As for question one, he assumes that there is a $p_n$ such that the definition of limit point is satisfied. Since $p$ is a limit point it follows that there is a $p_n$ as stated. As for the second question, I imagine he wrote it this way because it is the easiest to understand. There is a big enough $N$ that the inequality is satisfied for. It doesn't seem to be of any use to view it differently and it appears pedantic to argue one better than the other.

Comment: @Eoin, the definition of a limit point is: A point $p$ is a limit point of $E \subset X$, if every neighbourhood $N_r(x) \cap E - \{ p \} \neq \emptyset$. Where is the sequence in this?

Comment: @sidht why is there an 'x' in the definition?

Comment: @sidht choose a neighborhood about $p$ of radius $1/n$. Then, since $p$ is a limit point, $\exists p_n$ such that $p_n \in N_r(p)\cap E-\{p\}$.

Comment: @DavidPeterson, typo, I meant to write "p" instead of $x$

Comment: @Eoin, right since $p$ is a limit point, there is an element in the intersection, but why must that be a sequence? In fact claiming the existence is circular logic no? You are supposed to *prove* its existence?

Comment: @sidht You think he is claiming the existence of a sequence because the proof is too simple. It follows from the definition. He does not claim that it is the limit of a sequence. He constructs the sequence and then shows that $p$ is the limit of this sequence.

Comment: @Eoin
I think I get it now. Basically for each radius, there is a corresponding point. Together, that shows the existence of the sequence. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be an arbitrary positive integer. Since $\frac{1}{n}>0$, it follows from the definition of a limit point that
\begin{equation}B_{\frac{1}{n}}(p)  \cap E \setminus \{ p \} \neq \emptyset \, .
\end{equation}

Hence there is a point that we denote $p_n$ different from $p$ so that $d(p_n, p)<\frac{1}{n}$. Since $n$ was arbitrary it now follows that, for each positive integer $n$ there is a point $p_n \in E \setminus \{ p \}$ such that $d(p_n,p)<\frac{1}{n}$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. By the Archimedean property, there is a positive integer $N$ so that $N\varepsilon>1$. It now follows that $d(p_n,p)<\varepsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$.

Comment: I think I get it now. Basically for each radius, there is a corresponding point. Together, that shows the existence of the sequence.